# Using Bundle_Copy, importing content type is not working

Tags: nodes, importing-exporting

I've been trying stuff out with the Feeds module and decided it'd be better to clone a content type to use because of all the nodes it's creating. but i'm having trouble cloning the content type.  I've exported using the Bundle Copy module. then, in the code i change the 'type' and 'name' so as not to overwrite the original when importing. But when i import it's not really importing anything except the new name. i end with a new content type that only has a title and body

what could be wrong here that it's not really importing this data?

```
$data = array(
'bundles' => array(
'program_entry' => (object) array(
  'type' => 'program_entry',
  'name' => 'Program Entry',
  'base' => 'node_content',
  'module' => 'node',
  'description' => 'Use this for individual program entries',
  'help' => '',
  'has_title' => '1',
  'title_label' => 'Title',
  'custom' => '1',
  'modified' => '1',
  'locked' => '0',
  'disabled' => '0',
  'orig_type' => 'program_entry',
  'disabled_changed' => FALSE,
  'bc_entity_type' => 'node',
  ),
  ),
 'fields' => array(
 'field_feature_tags' => array(
  'translatable' => '0',
  'entity_types' => array(),
  'settings' => array(
    'max_length' => '255',
  ),
  'storage' => array(
    'type' => 'field_sql_storage',
    'settings' => array(),
    'module' => 'field_sql_storage',
    'active' => '1',
    'details' => array(
      'sql' => array(
        'FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT' => array(
          'field_data_field_feature_tags' => array(
            'value' => 'field_feature_tags_value',
            'format' => 'field_feature_tags_format',
          ),
        ),
        'FIELD_LOAD_REVISION' => array(
          'field_revision_field_feature_tags' => array(
            'value' => 'field_feature_tags_value',
            'format' => 'field_feature_tags_format',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'foreign keys' => array(
    'format' => array(
      'table' => 'filter_format',
      'columns' => array(
        'format' => 'format',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'indexes' => array(
    'format' => array(
      0 => 'format',
    ),
  ),
  'field_name' => 'field_feature_tags',
  'type' => 'text',
  'module' => 'text',
  'active' => '1',
  'locked' => '0',
  'cardinality' => '-1',
  'deleted' => '0',
  'columns' => array(
    'value' => array(
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => '255',
      'not null' => FALSE,
    ),
    'format' => array(
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => 255,
      'not null' => FALSE,
    ),
  ),
  'bundles' => array(
    'node' => array(
      0 => 'feature',
      1 => 'program_entry',
    ),
  ),
),
'field_invited_panelist' => array(
  'translatable' => '0',
  'entity_types' => array(),
  'settings' => array(
    'referenceable_types' => array(
      'panelist' => 'panelist',
      'article' => 0,
      'page' => 0,
      'event' => 0,
      'program_entry' => 0,
    ),
    'view' => array(
      'view_name' => '',
      'display_name' => '',
      'args' => array(),
    ),
  ),
  'storage' => array(
    'type' => 'field_sql_storage',
    'settings' => array(),
    'module' => 'field_sql_storage',
    'active' => '1',
    'details' => array(
      'sql' => array(
        'FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT' => array(
          'field_data_field_invited_panelist' => array(
            'nid' => 'field_invited_panelist_nid',
          ),
        ),
        'FIELD_LOAD_REVISION' => array(
          'field_revision_field_invited_panelist' => array(
            'nid' => 'field_invited_panelist_nid',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'foreign keys' => array(
    'nid' => array(
      'table' => 'node',
      'columns' => array(
        'nid' => 'nid',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'indexes' => array(
    'nid' => array(
      0 => 'nid',
    ),
  ),
  'field_name' => 'field_invited_panelist',
  'type' => 'node_reference',
  'module' => 'node_reference',
  'active' => '1',
  'locked' => '0',
  'cardinality' => '-1',
  'deleted' => '0',
  'columns' => array(
    'nid' => array(
      'type' => 'int',
      'unsigned' => TRUE,
      'not null' => FALSE,
    ),
  ),
  'bundles' => array(
    'node' => array(
      0 => 'program_entry',
    ),
  ),
),
'field_moderator' => array(
  'translatable' => '0',
  'entity_types' => array(),
  'settings' => array(
    'referenceable_types' => array(
      'moderator' => 'moderator',
      'article' => 0,
      'page' => 0,
      'date' => 0,
      'homepage_with_big_logo' => 0,
      'panel' => 0,
      'panelist' => 0,
      'program_entry' => 0,
      'time_span' => 0,
    ),
    'view' => array(
      'view_name' => '',
      'display_name' => '',
      'args' => array(),
    ),
  ),
  'storage' => array(
    'type' => 'field_sql_storage',
    'settings' => array(),
    'module' => 'field_sql_storage',
    'active' => '1',
    'details' => array(
      'sql' => array(
        'FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT' => array(
          'field_data_field_moderator' => array(
            'nid' => 'field_moderator_nid',
          ),
        ),
        'FIELD_LOAD_REVISION' => array(
          'field_revision_field_moderator' => array(
            'nid' => 'field_moderator_nid',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'foreign keys' => array(
    'nid' => array(
      'table' => 'node',
      'columns' => array(
        'nid' => 'nid',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'indexes' => array(
    'nid' => array(
      0 => 'nid',
    ),
  ),
  'field_name' => 'field_moderator',
  'type' => 'node_reference',
  'module' => 'node_reference',
  'active' => '1',
  'locked' => '0',
  'cardinality' => '1',
  'deleted' => '0',
  'columns' => array(
    'nid' => array(
      'type' => 'int',
      'unsigned' => TRUE,
      'not null' => FALSE,
    ),
  ),
  'bundles' => array(
    'node' => array(
      0 => 'program_entry',
    ),
  ),
),
'field_please_rsvp' => array(
  'translatable' => '0',
  'entity_types' => array(),
  'settings' => array(
    'max_length' => '255',
  ),
  'storage' => array(
    'type' => 'field_sql_storage',
    'settings' => array(),
    'module' => 'field_sql_storage',
    'active' => '1',
    'details' => array(
      'sql' => array(
        'FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT' => array(
          'field_data_field_please_rsvp' => array(
            'value' => 'field_please_rsvp_value',
            'format' => 'field_please_rsvp_format',
          ),
        ),
        'FIELD_LOAD_REVISION' => array(
          'field_revision_field_please_rsvp' => array(
            'value' => 'field_please_rsvp_value',
            'format' => 'field_please_rsvp_format',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'foreign keys' => array(
    'format' => array(
      'table' => 'filter_format',
      'columns' => array(
        'format' => 'format',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'indexes' => array(
    'format' => array(
      0 => 'format',
    ),
  ),
  'field_name' => 'field_please_rsvp',
  'type' => 'text',
  'module' => 'text',
  'active' => '1',
  'locked' => '0',
  'cardinality' => '1',
  'deleted' => '0',
  'columns' => array(
    'value' => array(
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => '255',
      'not null' => FALSE,
    ),
    'format' => array(
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => 255,
      'not null' => FALSE,
    ),
  ),
  'bundles' => array(
    'node' => array(
      0 => 'program_entry',
    ),
  ),
),
'field_program_attachments' => array(
  'translatable' => '0',
  'entity_types' => array(),
  'settings' => array(
    'display_field' => 0,
    'display_default' => 0,
    'uri_scheme' => 'public',
  ),
  'storage' => array(
    'type' => 'field_sql_storage',
    'settings' => array(),
    'module' => 'field_sql_storage',
    'active' => '1',
    'details' => array(
      'sql' => array(
        'FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT' => array(
          'field_data_field_program_attachments' => array(
            'fid' => 'field_program_attachments_fid',
            'display' => 'field_program_attachments_display',
            'description' => 'field_program_attachments_description',
          ),
        ),
        'FIELD_LOAD_REVISION' => array(
          'field_revision_field_program_attachments' => array(
            'fid' => 'field_program_attachments_fid',
            'display' => 'field_program_attachments_display',
            'description' => 'field_program_attachments_description',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'foreign keys' => array(
    'fid' => array(
      'table' => 'file_managed',
      'columns' => array(
        'fid' => 'fid',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'indexes' => array(
    'fid' => array(
      0 => 'fid',
    ),
  ),
  'field_name' => 'field_program_attachments',
  'type' => 'file',
  'module' => 'file',
  'active' => '1',
  'locked' => '0',
  'cardinality' => '-1',
  'deleted' => '0',
  'columns' => array(
    'fid' => array(
      'description' => 'The {file_managed}.fid being referenced in this     field.',
      'type' => 'int',
      'not null' => FALSE,
      'unsigned' => TRUE,
    ),
    'display' => array(
      'description' => 'Flag to control whether this file should be displayed     when viewing content.',
      'type' => 'int',
      'size' => 'tiny',
      'unsigned' => TRUE,
      'not null' => TRUE,
      'default' => 1,
    ),
    'description' => array(
      'description' => 'A description of the file.',
      'type' => 'text',
      'not null' => FALSE,
    ),
  ),
  'bundles' => array(
    'node' => array(
      0 => 'program_entry',
    ),
  ),
),
),
 'instances' => array(
 'field_feature_tags' => array(
  0 => array(
    'label' => 'Tags',
    'widget' => array(
      'weight' => '13',
      'type' => 'text_textfield',
      'module' => 'text',
      'active' => 1,
      'settings' => array(
        'size' => '60',
      ),
    ),
    'settings' => array(
      'text_processing' => '0',
      'user_register_form' => FALSE,
    ),
    'display' => array(
      'default' => array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'text_default',
        'settings' => array(),
        'module' => 'text',
        'weight' => 10,
      ),
      'teaser' => array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'hidden',
        'weight' => '4',
        'settings' => array(),
      ),
      'search_index' => array(
        'type' => 'hidden',
        'label' => 'above',
        'settings' => array(),
        'weight' => 0,
      ),
    ),
    'required' => 0,
    'description' => '',
    'default_value' => NULL,
    'field_name' => 'field_feature_tags',
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'bundle' => 'program_entry',
    'deleted' => '0',
  ),
),
'field_invited_panelist' => array(
  0 => array(
    'label' => 'Invited panelist',
    'widget' => array(
      'weight' => '7',
      'type' => 'options_buttons',
      'module' => 'options',
      'active' => 1,
      'settings' => array(),
    ),
    'settings' => array(
      'user_register_form' => FALSE,
    ),
    'display' => array(
      'default' => array(
        'label' => 'inline',
        'type' => 'node_reference_default',
        'weight' => '5',
        'settings' => array(),
        'module' => 'node_reference',
      ),
      'search_index' => array(
        'label' => 'inline',
        'type' => 'node_reference_default',
        'weight' => '5',
        'settings' => array(),
        'module' => 'node_reference',
      ),
      'teaser' => array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'hidden',
        'weight' => '6',
        'settings' => array(),
      ),
    ),
    'required' => 0,
    'description' => '',
    'default_value' => NULL,
    'field_name' => 'field_invited_panelist',
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'bundle' => 'program_entry',
    'deleted' => '0',
  ),
),
'field_moderator' => array(
  0 => array(
    'label' => 'Moderator',
    'widget' => array(
      'weight' => '6',
      'type' => 'options_select',
      'module' => 'options',
      'active' => 1,
      'settings' => array(),
    ),
    'settings' => array(
      'user_register_form' => FALSE,
    ),
    'display' => array(
      'default' => array(
        'label' => 'inline',
        'type' => 'node_reference_default',
        'weight' => '6',
        'settings' => array(),
        'module' => 'node_reference',
      ),
      'search_index' => array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'node_reference_default',
        'weight' => '6',
        'settings' => array(),
        'module' => 'node_reference',
      ),
      'teaser' => array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'hidden',
        'weight' => '5',
        'settings' => array(),
      ),
    ),
    'required' => 0,
    'description' => '',
    'default_value' => NULL,
    'field_name' => 'field_moderator',
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'bundle' => 'program_entry',
    'deleted' => '0',
  ),
),
'field_please_rsvp' => array(
  0 => array(
    'label' => 'Please RSVP',
    'widget' => array(
      'weight' => '10',
      'type' => 'text_textfield',
      'module' => 'text',
      'active' => 1,
      'settings' => array(
        'size' => '160',
      ),
    ),
    'settings' => array(
      'text_processing' => '1',
      'user_register_form' => FALSE,
    ),
    'display' => array(
      'default' => array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'text_default',
        'weight' => '9',
        'settings' => array(),
        'module' => 'text',
      ),
      'search_index' => array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'text_default',
        'weight' => '9',
        'settings' => array(),
        'module' => 'text',
      ),
      'teaser' => array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'hidden',
        'weight' => '8',
        'settings' => array(),
      ),
    ),
    'required' => 0,
    'description' => '',
    'default_value' => array(
      0 => array(
        'value' => 'Please RSVP <a href="mailto:events@xxxx.net?subject=I will attend the SOME DATEth SPN event">events@xxxxxxx.net</a>',
        'format' => 'full_html',
      ),
    ),
    'field_name' => 'field_please_rsvp',
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'bundle' => 'program_entry',
    'deleted' => '0',
  ),
),
'field_program_attachments' => array(
  0 => array(
    'label' => 'program_attachments',
    'widget' => array(
      'weight' => '9',
      'type' => 'file_generic',
      'module' => 'file',
      'active' => 1,
      'settings' => array(
        'progress_indicator' => 'throbber',
      ),
    ),
    'settings' => array(
      'file_directory' => '',
      'file_extensions' => 'txt pdf',
      'max_filesize' => '25 MB',
      'description_field' => 0,
      'user_register_form' => FALSE,
    ),
    'display' => array(
      'default' => array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'file_default',
        'weight' => '8',
        'settings' => array(),
        'module' => 'file',
      ),
      'search_index' => array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'file_default',
        'weight' => '8',
        'settings' => array(),
        'module' => 'file',
      ),
      'teaser' => array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'hidden',
        'weight' => '7',
        'settings' => array(),
      ),
    ),
    'required' => 0,
    'description' => '',
    'field_name' => 'field_program_attachments',
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'bundle' => 'program_entry',
    'deleted' => '0',
  ),
  ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: There are also a few bundle properties that need to be changed. Check out this [article](https://www.drupal.org/node/1252462). Do you want to create content types that are identical?

Comment: hey thanks, almost identical. minus a couple of fields.